# is it possible to remove the dtype from tensor in pytorch?

Tags: computer-vision, pytorch, torch, torchvision

```
targets-> [{'boxes': tensor([[ 23.7296,  28.9209, 122.0997, 213.2374]], device='cuda:0',
       dtype=torch.float64), 'labels': tensor([1], device='cuda:0'), 'area': tensor([18131.2344], device='cuda:0'), 'iscrowd': tensor([0], device='cuda:0')}]
```

right now the boxes has the dtype=torch.float64 is it possible it just looks like

```
targets-> [{'boxes': tensor([[ 23.7296,  28.9209, 122.0997, 213.2374]], device='cuda:0',), 'labels': tensor([1], device='cuda:0'), 'area': tensor([18131.2344], device='cuda:0'), 'iscrowd': tensor([0], device='cuda:0')}]
```

Answer (score 3):

All tensors have a [`dtype`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch.torch.dtype) attribute, no exceptions. However, PyTorch has a [default float dtype](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensor_attributes.html#torch.torch.dtype), usually `torch.float32` (single precision 32bit floating point). When displaying tensors with this default dtype, it is omitted. However, your `boxes` tensor has a *non*-default dtype, `torch.float64` and therefore it is being displayed.
You can use the [`.to()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.to) command to cast this tensor to the default `torch.float32` dtype, and consequently make PyTorch not explicitly display the dtype:

```py
targets[0]['boxes'] = targets[0]['boxes'].to(dtype=torch.float32)  #.to() in _not_ an in-place operation
```

This will result in

> ```
> In [*]: targets
> Out[*]:
> [{'boxes': tensor([[ 23.7296,  28.9209, 122.0997, 213.2374]], device='cuda:0'),
>   'labels': tensor([1], device='cuda:0'),
>   'area': tensor([18131.2344], device='cuda:0'),
>   'iscrowd': tensor([0], device='cuda:0')}]
> ```